# Asp.net core, redirect to a static html page if URL has Https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Redirect to a static html page if the url contains "https"

After accepting the warning "Not trusted (Since using https)". I would like to redirect the users to a static page with some useful message.

Https connection wont fail, I just dont want to load application if its a Https request. I want to load a static Html page instead.

Ex: https://localhost:1234
then redirect to a static page

Right Now What I have:

if the url is http://localhost:3221 it redirects to HomeController -> Index Action

It is more like adding conventional routing for Https request, I dont know if it is possible.

Comment: Does your server handle HTTPS connections correctly? If not, then this is not possible because modern browsers won't fallback to HTTP if a HTTPS connection fails.

Comment: The Https request doesn't fail in my case, but I dont want to load application. Instead I would like to show some static page.

Comment: *“Not trusted (Since using https)”* – Does that really sound like a good idea to you…? :/

Comment: You can do this with a simple piece of middleware.  Just know that EVERY request will come through it, even requests for css/js/etc.  Here is some really good info on middleware:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a simple middleware for this. Something like this should do the job:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // check if the request is *not* using the HTTPS scheme
    if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
    {
        // redirect to some relative URL (see note below!)
        context.Response.Redirect("/no-https-error.html");

        return;
    }

    // otherwise continue with the request pipeline
    await next();
});
```

Since this is [a middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) it affects every requests that reach the middleware at the point you have inserted into the pipeline. So if you would place this before `app.UseStaticFiles()`, then this middleware will also prevent you from reaching static files, including that error file you redirect to. If you want to do that, you would have to make the redirect contain an absolute path to a `http://` address instead:

```
var url = "http://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + "/no-https-error.html";
context.Response.Redirect(url);
```

Comment: I have added a html page in the same directory as Startup.cs, but it is still going to Homecontroller -> Index action.

Comment: app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (!context.Request.IsHttps)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/htmlpage.html");
                    return;
                }
                await next();
            });


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

Comment: It is working, Thanks. I was trying with https request.

Comment: Instead of redirecting to a static page, can we redirect to a https ://localhost:1234/Controller/SomeAction ?

Comment: You can enter any URL in the redirect there. You just need to make sure that if you stay on https for the redirect, then you need to put an exception for that exact route into the middleware, so it does not keep redirecting to itself.

Comment: I have added context.Response.Redirect("/htmlpage.html"). the url it is redirecting is https://localhost:3112/htmlpage.html and it say can't open the page

Comment: Are you sure that file exists? Does that page work when you comment out the middleware?